# Cambiar variable impresa en PHP por estrellas

Tags: php

Hola amigos un saludo.

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

if ($redondea>='1'){

echo $redondea;
    
}else{


}

?>
```

Después de un calculo sencillo estoy imprimiendo el valor que da la división en la variable $redondea

Esta variable me da números enteros del 1 al 5, estoy buscando la forma de como cambiar el número de la variable por estrellas, estoy intentando hacer un pequeño sistema de calificaciones por estrellas, pero actualmente en base de datos estoy guardando la calificación de cada usuario, solo que no se como podría hacer lo siguiente:

Si la variable $redondea es igual a 4 entonces no debería imprimir el nro 4 estoy buscando que cambie ese nro 4 por 4 estrellas.

Si alguien me puede guiar como podría hacer algo como eso seria de gran ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te refieres a un `if ($redondea == 4) $redondea = '****'; echo $redondea;` ?  Aunque si lo vas a sacar enseguida no hace ni falta cambiar la variable, así tambien funciona:  `if ($redondea == 4) echo '****';`

Comment: Si te refieres literalmente a estrellas, puedes usar fontawesome, es una librería de iconos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo sencillo, podes hacer 5 imágenes cada una con las estrellas correspondientes, luego:

```
if($redondea == '1'){
   $redondea = "<img src='1estrella.png'>";
}elseif{$redondea == '2'){
   $redondea = "<img src='2estrella.png'>";
}elseif{$redondea == '3'){
   $redondea = "<img src='3estrella.png'>";
}elseif{$redondea == '4'){
   $redondea = "<img src='4estrella.png'>";
}elseif{$redondea == '5'){
   $redondea = "<img src='5estrella.png'>";
}else{
   $redondea = '';
}


if ($redondea>='1'){

echo $redondea;
    
}else{


}
```